# Programmatically disable Keyboard & Mouse

Tags: winapi

Is there a way to disable keyboard & mouse?

Ideally I'm looking for a solution whereby I could completely disable mouse and *almost* disable the keyboard - bar one key combination, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. So, once <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is pressed - the PC will go to a mute stage (no mouse/keyboard) until <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is pressed again.

Comment: you want to do this for your app or for the entire system?

Comment: I wanted the scope to be the entire PC, which is what the answer does I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have a look at ***"BlockInput Function"***

[refer MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646290.aspx)

Comment: hi i have not tried this but thought of helping you with MSDN. let me know whether it was helpful to you or not.

Comment: starman. Is there a way to toggle BlockInput using the keyboard?;) Say by leaving a reserved combination of keys unblocked?

Comment: @Dmitry i am not sure about that. Please do inform me if u find some way of that kind.